# Why won't my custom login page CSS load?

Tags: css, login, wp-login-form

Hoping for some help here as I'm scratching my head.  I'm trying to create a custom login page for my site which has gone rather well until I try to add in a custom CSS to make it look pretty.  I'm trying to add in the style-login.css file using the following:

```
// add a custom css file for login page
function nb_login_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style('nublue-login',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-login.css',
            FALSE,
            NULL,
            all);
    if ( ! has_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_print_styles' ) ){
        add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_print_styles', 11 );
    }
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'nb_login_style');
```

However the style-login.css file is never being inserted into the header of my page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works just fine for me, other than small kink that `all` should be quoted string `'all'`. But as far as WP queue is concerned it's valid.

Comment: I tried quoting the 'all' but that didn't make a difference.  When looking at the source of my login page I still only see the main style.css being loaded.  You can see for yourself here - [link]http://www.nublue.com/?page_id=587 @Rarst

Comment: Then it might be you are including this code with wrong timing or in file that isn't running. As above — simply dropping your snippet into mu-plugin worked fine for me, the issue is not with the code you provided.

Comment: The code was inserted at the bottom of my themes functions.php.  I tried moving it to the top and no change.  I know that this is being executed as other actions are working just fine.  Do you have any other suggestions for where to put it @Rarst?

Comment: Not really, I don't have a guess why wouldn't it work from `functions.php`. Same page check — you realize that you are using a hook that is only for login pages, right?

Comment: Yep.  I'm only trying to load it for my custom login page.  This is really doing my head in.  Thanks for trying to help anyway. @Rarst

Comment: _How much_ custom? :) Does it actually call this hook? Had you checked if it's working on _normal_ login page?

Comment: Great idea @Rarst.  I undid all the hooks that I used to change my login pages around and checked on the default page and all of a sudden my CSS was there.  Now I need to work out why my new page is not being recognised as a login page :).

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code in your theme's functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'nb_login_style' ) ) :
    function nb_login_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'nublue-login', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style-login.css' );
    }
    add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'nb_login_style' );
endif;
```

Above code was loosely taken from:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form#Styling_Your_Login

Also, I have a plugin I created awhile back that sounds like it does exactly what you're trying to do, might be worth taking a look:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-customize/

Comment: How is this different from what OP is doing?

Comment: It omits the `if ( ! has_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_print_styles' ) ){..}` if statement.